# Какой получается результат при делении целых чисел на си

Tags: c

Вопрос простой. Но меня беспокоит всегда ли получается так что при деление целых чисел остаток просто отбрасывается или возможны ситуации когда происходит округление.
Пример

```
int i = 0;

i = 0/32; i => 0
i = 1/32; i => 0
...
i = 31/32; i => 0
....
i = 35/32; i => 1
i = 63/32; i => 1
```

Или возможны другие ситуации?

Comment: при делении целого числа на переменную си, результат зависит от содержимого переменной ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Невозможны. Всегда выдается целая часть частного.

[Импортный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division)